# Unlock shared mutex in another thread

Tags: c++

I am trying to move a unique_lock of shared_mutex to another thread to achieve my design goals.

Please see the example code below. The code works if I replace std::shared_mutex with std::mutex

```
using namespace std;

shared_mutex shared_mutex_;
{
  unique_lock<shared_mutex> lock_{shared_mutex_};

  thread t{[](unique_lock<shared_mutex> &&lock) { lock.unlock(); },
           move(lock_)};

  t.join();
}

if (shared_mutex_.try_lock()) { // False
  cout << "Lock shared_mutex_ successful\n";
  shared_mutex_.unlock();
}
```

My design goals are:

- Calling a function should start a worker thread if a unique lock can be acquired.
- A worker thread has unique access to all resources. When a worker thread is running, no other worker can be started.
- std::future will be used to check whether the work has finished.
- If the worker is not running, resources should have shared access.

I am trying to used std::shared_mutex or std::shared_timed_mutex to achieve my design goal. But it doesn't seem to be working. Please let me know if you have other ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Using `std::mutex` here is also Undefined Behavior. If it looks like it works, it's an unfortunate coincidence.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yes, passing reference to the mutex solved my problem!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how passing references to the `mutex` solved your problem. Can you explain further?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I guess OP captured the mutex by reference and constructed the unique_lock inside the lambda. Kinda contradicts OPs first point tho.

Comment: My idea was to constructed the unique_lock inside the lambda. The parent thread will wait for a small duration to catch exceptions thrown by the worker thread during the worker's early initialization (including fail to acquire lock). However I am having problems catching the exception. That's a separate issue...